# what yum repo do I need for nfs-utils

Tags: yum, nfs

I downloaded yum but have 0 repos. What yum repo do I need for nfs-utils so I can do this tutoial:

http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/linux-and-open-source/set-up-easy-file-sharing-with-nfs-on-linux/#.

Comment: What OS are you using? Distros that use `yum` come with it pre-installed.

Comment: I'm using mint os 16

Comment: If you don't mind using the builtin package system that comes with mint, try `apt-get install nfs-utils`.

Comment: thanks but using that I get:  Unable to locate package nfs-utils